# Does it make sense to use "LIMIT 1" in a query "SELECT 1 ..."?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

The question should be clear enough, but is it of any advantage to use instead of

`SELECT 1 FROM table ...`

`SELECT 1 FROM table ... LIMIT 1`?

Comment: Those are 2 very different things. The first query will retrieve a `1` for every record of your table and the second will return just one record. So, is there any advantage to use instead of the other?, no, because they are not comparable

Comment: @Lamak: yeah, you are right... I forgot to mention that I meant with advantage to check if an entry exists...

Comment: Note that in every modern DBMS you have not any performance gain from using `SELECT 1` versus `SELECT *` in an `EXISTS` subquery, and `SELECT *` should be used instead.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Let's say your table has a million rows...

```
SELECT 1 FROM table ...
```

Will return the value `1`, a million times...

```
SELECT 1 FROM table ... LIMIT 1
```

Will return the value `1`, one time.

---

**EDIT**

You mention that you're specifically interested in regards to an `EXISTS` check.  `EXISTS` stops processing after the first row is found (which is why `EXISTS` is more efficient than `IN` in this case), so with this in mind, there isn't a functional difference between these two queries:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA ta
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM TableB tb
    WHERE tb.ID = ta.ID
);
```

And

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA ta
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM TableB tb
    WHERE tb.ID = ta.ID
    LIMIT 1
);
```

Comment: perfect explanation, exactly what I wanted to know! thank you very much Michael! :)

Comment: Note that in every modern DBMS you have not any performance gain from using `SELECT 1` versus `SELECT *` in an `EXISTS` subquery.